# Removing messages from a postfix queue based on message body content

Tags: postfix

I would like to delete some messages from an existing postfix queue based on a string match in the message body.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is fairly simple:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/deferred/ -type f \
        -exec grep -l 'body string here' '{}' \; | \
    xargs -n1 basename | xargs -n1 postsuper -d
```

Adjust path (if non-default), and the -n1 in the second xargs isn't strictly needed, but gives a better sense that it's actually doing something.

Comment: He didn't specify which queue.

Comment: True. For a different queue, use that instead of deferred in the find portion. postsuper works on a number of queues -- hold, incoming, active and deferred -- or you can specify it at the end ( ... | xargs -n1 -i postsuper -d '{}' bounce )

Comment: And to dry-run this (count how many mails would be deleted without actually doing that), you can run the command while replacing the last part `xargs -n1 postsuper -d` with `wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should end that with > delfile.txt then you can review what you deleted and then delete the text file